# ¿Como hacer una recaudación con múltiple destino en MercadoPago?

Tags: php, mercadopago

Estoy usando MercadoPago en Argentina, para mi aplicación y me gustaría saber si es posible dividir el pago en 2 cuentas, por ejemplo si ingresa un pago con un monto de 200 pesos, envio 150 pesos a una cuenta y 50 pesos a otra cuenta.

Mi Codigo es (PHP):

```
$payment_data = array(
    "transaction_amount" => $total_amount,
    "token" => $cardToken,
    "description" => $payment_description,
    "installments" => 1,
    "payer" => $payer
);

$payment = $mp->post("/v1/payments", $payment_data);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Mercado Pago* ofrece un modelo de *Marketplace*, que permite hacer lo que necesitás. En este modelo están involucradas tres partes: Comprador, vendedor y un tercero, que cobra una comisión o porcentaje del pago.

Lo que tenés que hacer es vincular a los distintos vendedores a un *Marketplace* (Fijate la documentación de [*connect*](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/custom-checkout/mercadopago-connect/)  y también la de [*checkout* personalizado](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/custom-checkout/get-started/) que dice cómo hacerlo), y automáticamente por cada pago se efectuará la distribución del mismo según cómo se indique en cada pago. (También podes optar por un *checkout básico*).

A partir de tu código, el nuevo snippet debería ser algo así:

```
$payment_data = array( 
    "transaction_amount" => $total_amount, 
    "token" => $cardToken, 
    "description" => $payment_description, 
    "installments" => 1, 
    "payer" => $payer 
    "application_fee" => $comission_amount //Monto que va a cobrar el marketplace
); 
$payment = $mp->post("/v1/payments", $payment_data);
```

Comment: Y si se tratase de más de una cuenta destino ?

Comment: En ese caso hay que hacer un pago usando el modelo de carrito de compras denominado SPLIT. Imposible hacerlo funcionar. Errores por todos lados, API sin documentación clara. Proceso o flujo inexistente. No te dicen qué campos son requeridos u obligatorios. Desastroso. Te obligan a utilizar otras formas de realizar lo que necesitas. Increible.