# Retención de cargo

Tags: mercadopago

Mi cliente quiere hacer cobros por rentas, a los cuáles se les haría un cobro adicional por mal uso del equipo.
Es decir, estamos buscando hacer dos cobros, uno por el servicio y otro que se quede pendiente o "congelado".
Esto se puede hacer con MercadoPago? vi el atributo deferred_capture pero no encontré nada más al respecto.

Comment: Podrías revisar esta pregunta http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43566/como-hacer-una-recaudación-con-múltiple-destino-en-mercadopago

Answer (score 0):

En la documentación menciona "Autorización y Captura", es como una reserva de fondos. 
https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/custom-checkout/two-step-payments/